# Why does MUI DatePicker prevent rendering in my project (working sandbox MRE included?)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I created a codesandbox with a minimal working implementation of MUI's Datepicker:

https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-pond-fb4rm?file=/src/App.js

*Edited to add my index.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {DatePicker, LocalizationProvider} from "@mui/lab";
import {TextField} from "@mui/material";
import AdapterDateFns from "@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns";

ReactDOM.render(
  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
    <DatePicker
      renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} />}
      value={null}
      onChange={() => null}
    />
  </LocalizationProvider>
  , document.getElementById('root')
)
```

This implementation throws errors in my project (prevents rendering), although I have the same versions installed. I linked my package-lock file for good measure in case I'm wrong.

Clearly not a bug, and seemingly not a mismatch in package versions, what else could be causing this?

[package-lock.json](http://jsonblob.com/925036937845424128)

[image: screenshot of errors thrown]

Comment: Your codesandbox implementation isn't about your problem. Without your current code, impossible understand the reason for the errors

Comment: @VitaliyRayets I've edited my original question to add the code. It's as barebones as can be, which leads me to believe the answer lies in my package-lock file

Comment: You have error from `MobileDatePicker`, but in code you use `DatePicker`, i think you miss something

Comment: What is "the above error" listed in the first stack trace?

Comment: @Codebling "The above error" is identical to the one you see below (Uncaught TypeError) - that's my bad for cropping the way I did

Comment: @VitaliyRayets I see what you're saying, but that's all happening in the library

Comment: I tried with your package-lock.json and I still can't get the line numbers to match up. It looks like it's trying to read `utils.formats.keyboardDate` but `formats` is undefined. I'm not sure why that may be. I don't see the error in the codesandbox that was linked to. Are you able to post a codesandbox that does reproduce it?

Comment: Are you using `ThemeProvider`? (Here are [a](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/30068) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70532844/675721) [links](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues?q=cannot+read+properties+of+undefined) for my own reference)

Comment: Can you show us the top most error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suspected, the clue was in my package-lock.json. Note to self: Always a good idea to have a look there when issue has been isolated and confirmed unique to a given project!

I had two different versions of @date-io/date-fns installed:

- 1.x.x (entry in package-json)
- 2.x.x (installed as dependency)