# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '8')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

This is my first time posting and I am a junior Frontend developer so please go easy on me.

This has me very confused and I've looked, tested and for some reason the Inputlabel from Material UI (ver. 5) is not working on this side of the website I am developing. I used inputlabel and date picker on the home page and they work with no problems. But suddenly trying to make a user profile form... Well, it's starting to give me trouble. Literally copying what is in the documentation and still get this issue.

When I click on the Input everythig on the page disappears. Opening the Chrome Inspector gives me the error that's in the title. And I am truly clueless. Posting my code to see if someone cand lend me a bit of help here. Thank you in advance.

```
    import React from 'react';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { Grid } from '@mui/material';
import { Box } from '@mui/system';
import { Container } from '@mui/material';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/lab";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/lab";
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
//import '../User/components/styles/UserStyles.scss';

const UserProfileTxt = () => {

//DOB picker
const [dob, setDob] = React.useState(new Date())

//Nationality Picker

 const [nationality, setNationality] = React.useState('');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setNationality(event.target.value);

  };
    
    return (
        <Container>
            <Grid container>
                <Grid sx={{ flexDirection: 'column', display: 'flex' }}>
                    <TextField sx={{mt:'0.5rem', mb:'0.5rem'}} variant='outlined' label='Nombre' />
                    <TextField sx={{mt:'0.5rem', mb:'0.5rem'}} variant='outlined' label='Apellido' />
                    <TextField sx={{mt:'0.5rem', mb:'0.5rem'}}variant='outlined' label='E-mail' />
                    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120, mt:'0.5rem', mb:'1rem' }}>
                        <FormControl fullWidth>
                            <InputLabel id="NationalityUSERHIKLUB">Nacionalidad</InputLabel>
                            <Select
                             labelId="Nacionalidad"
                             id="Naccionalidad"
                            value={nationality}
                            label="Nationalidad"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            >
                            <MenuItem value={1}>Ten</MenuItem>
                            </Select>
                        </FormControl>
                    </Box>
                    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                            <DatePicker
                                label="Seleccióna fecha de Nacimiento"
                                value={dob}
                                onChange={(newValue) => {
                                    setDob(newValue);
                                }}
                                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                            />
                        </LocalizationProvider>
                </Grid>
                <Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Container>
    );
};

export default UserProfileTxt;
```

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in a codesandbox/pen and share the link?  I copied your code into a codesandbox and it seems to work (https://codesandbox.io/s/basictextfields-material-demo-forked-d83ub?file=/demo.js).

Comment: I also [can't reproduce your issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-darkness-w5s1t?file=/src/App.js). Can you post the full error log?

Comment: @Summer Here is The error log https://imgur.com/a/F7HLBaH I did a capture on Imgur because It's a lot easier to visualize. Thank you!

Comment: @SteveGomez Here is The error log https://imgur.com/a/F7HLBaH I did a capture on Imgur because It's a lot easier to visualize. Thank you!

Comment: @VictoriaLaplana This looks like an error with the popup window from the date picker. But I can't figure out why it happens. Did you forget to install `date-fns` as a dependency? You need that for the date picker to work. If it's not that, I have no clue, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I solved my own question.

This is probably a bug, but I didn't add this to the original question because I seriously didn't think it was going to be related. Despite that, I am going to share it in case someone is having issues as well.

So, this form I am doing is inside a `<Tabs/>` component, which I costumized using `<ThemeProvider/>` and `<CreateTheme/>`. Started basically breaking my code down seeing where the error could stem from. Finally, I noticed that it could be the `<ThemeProvider/>` on the tabs. And sure enough, once I removed both `<ThemeProvider/>` and `<CreateTheme/>` The date picker and dropdown menu were working fine.

Sorry I didn't address it before but **I seriously did not think it was going to be related to the issue at hand**

So, long story short:
**DO NOT USE THEMEPROVIDER WHEN USING TABS ON MUI VER 5. USE STYLED COMPONENTS INSTEAD AND GET THE SAME RESULT WITH A LOT LESS ISSUES.** I suppose there is some sort of conflict with that and the tabs component.

Thanks to anyone who answered.

Comment: It sounds more like you were passing an invalid value to `createTheme` when generating the theme and not an issue with `ThemeProvider`/`Tabs` itself.